# Sign up and login form in android

Tags: android

previously i create android app in which i store sign up data in shared preferences and using this data i successful  login in my app. drawback of this method is that every time i follow complete procedure of sign up and then login because shared preference is temporary store data in mobile. and i don't login my old email id because old id is not stored in preference. every time new email overwrite the previous.
but now i want to create login form that work like original app login form.means once i create account using sign up and after that i login with my id... if i open my app again instead of  follow complete  sign up procedure I just login with my id.

Comment: what do  you want ? make it simple

Comment: how? please  help.Because I am new in android development. I want every time user install application. so he will login from existing email id instead of follow all sign up process because in my app user install app again and follow all sign up process because i store sign p data in sahred preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SharedPreferences** is the temporary storage option available in android. The data stored within lasts until user uninstalls the application or manually clear the cache/memory from application manager.
What you want is not possible locally. You does have to do with webservices. Basic outline is your sign up data moved to server.
 Each time user login credentials will be matched with data stored on server via webservice.

Comment: ok. i got your point so i also post my activity data to serve using volley. so after this what i do.i get back response from server??so i know how to post data but don't know how to get response back so can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so much clear but What I have got from it is , i think you want to check if the user has alrady an account then the procedure of getting sign up should be skipped else if he has not already signed up then he should navigate directly to sign up activity rather then the sign in activity

If it is so , then the following directions are applicable

1.On starting of main activity check if user has email id and password saved in shared preferences , check if the email id and password is there and if the shared preference is not null, its mean he has already have and account , so the sign up process should be  skipped

here is the demo pseudo code of the solution given above

```
1. if (sharedPrefrences.getEmailId("your key name")!=null && !sharedPrefrences.getEmailId("your key name").isEmpty)
 { //if the shared prefrences is not null and has value 
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity,loginActivity);
}else{

startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity,loginActivity);
}
```

so this is a small description on how you can use your login preference. I didnt mentioned the procedure of shared preference as you already have implemented it.

> Edit 2  in case of Server

If you have server for checking log in then do the following 
 1. Keep track if the user is running your app for the very first time , so that you can show him the sign up activity , once he has signed up , then it should not come back to show the user when ever he run his app again. Better thing is not to worry about activities make two button and show him login and register button so the user is intelligent enough to not to create account again once he has created.

2. Once the login of the user has been created on the  next time , on the log in button you should ask him to enter the credentials let say email id or user name and password , fetch those user name and password and send to server via your designed api , and then you are good to go from the server reply , let say error code of server is 0 and message is logged in , show user this message ,  let supposer error code is 1 , then message could be incorrect user name or password  and on error 3 you can show user name does not exist , so this is jsut an idea I am giving to you that its easy to implement you own login service.

I hope this would help  you.

Comment: In my app i have two buttons on my home screen login and register.
1)if i click on register a form will appear and i fill it and then register.
2) if i click on login button and fill login form after pressing login button my app will crash because my shared preference is empty. i don't follow sign up  procedure.

Comment: But i want this i created one an account in my app. and again and again i install my app or restart my phone if i open my app i just login in my app. i don't register in my app again.

drawback of my previous process is i create my account again if i reinstall my app because my data in shared preference is not permanent storage

Comment: else if you give me your email id i will sent u my code then may be you will got my point

Comment: ok. i got your point so i also post my activity data to serve using volley. so after this what i do.i get back response from server??so i know how to post data but don't know how to get response back so can you help?

Comment: we are here to help you , but with out clear question we can not , why dont you use facebook login authorization in you app

Comment: if you have server then you can implement login process on server side , I am updating my answer in according to server case

Comment: User create account if user is already registered than again He/she can't create account if he/she again create account than it will say already registered and we simply login how to do code in Android?

Comment: if i send login details to server then what is the nxt process??

Comment: how to get repky bck from server. becuz i hv done to post data but dont knw how to get reply bck uding volley..plz hlp r shre any useful link that solv my problm

Comment: how can i add facebook login?

Comment: do you have api set for logging in ? if so then check what is the return type of api and what parameters is it returning , let say it is returning in the form of json then you need to parse it , and then you need to take out key values as I discussed above , let say it is returning you the message and error code then you have to get these as keys and their values

Comment: how to use api , how to send parameters and get the reply back from api , I am giving you the tutorail , in this he is using weather Api , you can learn for your case and you can learn how to parse the json also . SO this is good to learn the basic concept 
here you go
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android--cms-21587

Comment: i user json responce then dont knw how to implemnt